# Magic Trackpad is not scrolling or rotating

Tags: macos, touchpad, magic-trackpad

I've recently bought Apple's Magic Trackpad and was informed about its requirements for Snow Leopard.

I have currently installed Snow Leopard on my Mac but my Magic Trackpad still isn't doing all of its functions such as scrolling and rotating.

Does anyone know what my problem might be?

Comment: We need to know more. What exactly is working? What exactly doesn't work? Can you tell us 1) what you want to achieve 2) what you're doing and 3) what happens instead? Also, can you show us a screenshot of *System Preferences* for the Magic Trackpad?

Answer (score 0):

I can only hypothesize based on your question:

- Check the batteries, get new ones
- Make sure you have a compatible machine (32bit, 64bit?)
- Go to the Apple Website and re-install the driver
- Restart your machine after installing a new driver
- Make sure you purchased from a reputable source, one that wouldn't provide you with a counterfeit product
- Return the mouse, it may be defective